# Is it possible to find button by view, and not findViewById?

Tags: java, android

I'm wondering if it is possible to find the button in the way I want. Because I need to make a temporary button from the button that has been clicked.

This code gives an error:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.view);
}


view cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

That is obviously, because I'm using the findViewById() method, and therefore the program is expecting an Id, not a View. Is there maybe an other method to find the right button?

Comment: You want to `make` a temporary button? Why are you calling `findViewById` if you need to make a new button? Do you mean that later you want to find the temporary button that you created?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it good enough. My English is not good enough for this :P But I will try.

For example, what I want to get from the button:
int i = button.getId();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view parameter IS the button that was clicked.  You can simply cast it to Button

Comment: Like this: Button button = (Button) view; ?